# Postgres SQL error: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification" DESPITE constrain being set

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.3

(sorry, there are many similar questions on SO but none I could find that match well enough)

Attempting to upsert to a Postgres RDS table via a temp table...

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

# assume db_engine is already set up

with db_engine.connect() as conn:

            conn.execute(sa.text("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table"))
            build_temp_table = f"""
                CREATE TABLE temp_table (
                unique_id        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                date             TIMESTAMP,
                amount           NUMERIC,
                UNIQUE (unique_id)
                );
                """
            conn.execute(sa.text(build_temp_table))

            upsert_sql_string = """
                INSERT INTO production_table(unique_id, date, amount)
                SELECT unique_id, date, amount FROM temp_table
                ON CONFLICT (unique_id)
                DO UPDATE SET 
                            date = excluded.date,
                            amount  = excluded.amount
                """
            conn.execute(sa.text(upsert_sql_string))
```

Note: `production_table` is configured the identically to `temp_table`

Other methods I have tried include:

- Specifying `unique_id` as PRIMARY KEY or `UNIQUE` in table definition
- Running `ALTER TABLE temp_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (unique_id)` after creating `temp_table`

Regardless of what I do, I get the error:

`psycopg2.errors.InvalidColumnReference: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`

Thanks

Comment: The `PK` or `UNIQUE` would need to be on `production_table`, that is where the conflict would be.

Comment: yes, I neglected to mention that `production_table` is configured identically to `temp_table`

Comment: Either it isn't or there is `search_path` setting that is pointing at another version of  `production_table`